# when I start to run flutter doctor it say X Android SDK file not found: adb. how I solve this problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

```
C:\Users\ASUS>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1526], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X Android SDK file not found: adb.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1) ` `
[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: android sdk are not installed. you can get it via android studio or install it manually

Comment: sdk install i am sure 

Comment: try this command  `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`

Comment: can you check  platform-tools are installed or not.

Answer (score 2):

`android_sdk/platform-tools/` is not installed in your computer or you made mistake in installing and adding to you path

if your using Android Studio go to `settings` then `System Settings` go to `Android SDK` and install `Android SDK Platform-Tools`,

if it didnt help reinstall platform-tools, this might be helpful

you can follow link to install it manually [SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
but remember to add the path of android bin folder in your `env`

for more info you can read [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-unable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio/#:%7E:text=This%20generally%20occurs%20if%20the,Tools%20(as%20shown%20above).)

Comment: op has already mentioned that sdk is installed. and your manual installation is not relevant for flutter environment.

Comment: but I think sdk installation is incomplete.

Comment: This fixed it for me. SDK was installed but this was good to find location. Also way to install any missing modules like cmd line tools

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **SDK Manager** from Settings.
2. Select **Android SDK** from Left Sidebar.
3. Select **SDK Tools**.
4. Check **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)** and download and
   install it.
5. Run **flutter doctor** again

Hope solved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check Also Links :D

step 1 : First we need Android SDK path on your computer

[image: Android SDK path on your computer]

step 2 : Open my computer and paste the path

[image: my computer and paste the path]

step 3 : Find SDK folder here and open

[image: Find SDK folder here and open]

step 4 : Copy 'platform-tools' this folder

[image: Copy 'platform-tools']

step 5 : Paste folder here (android studio path location)

[image: Paste folder here]

step 6 : Now Check and Enjoy :D

step 7 : Now you can like if this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case at Windows 10 :
[image]

the problem was solved as follows:

1- download and extract [platform-tools zip file](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools) in android_sdk directory  (after delete old platform-tools directory).

2- run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

3- run `flutter doctor -v` , and get `• No issues found!` message :)

[image]